# Separate connect and read timeouts for JBossWS

Tags: web-services, jboss, connection-timeout, jbossws

Can anyone give a hint how to set separate connect and read timeouts when calling external webservice from JBossWS-Native client?

All I've found so far is how to set a single timeout:

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("org.jboss.ws.timeout", 1000);
```

The same question (unanswered for a long time) on JBoss forum:
http://community.jboss.org/thread/103582

Vesions in use: jbossws-native-2.0.1.SP2 and jbossws-native-3.1.1.GA on JBoss 4.2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examined the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.ws.native/jbossws-native-core/3.2.1.GA/org/jboss/ws/core/client/transport/NettyClient.java#NettyClient.invokeInternal%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,boolean,java.util.Map,java.util.Map%29) - it's not possible at all. There's single timeout.

Went to [jbossws jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS) willing to file a feature request.
But found [JBWS-3114](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-3114) and this [message](http://community.jboss.org/message/562353#562353):

> I've added this two properties
>   "javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout",
>   "javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout" to cxf and native stack for the
>   stack agnostic timeout configuration:

```
public void testConfigureTimeout() throws Exception   
{ 
  //Set timeout until a connection is established 
  ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().
          put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", "6000");
  //Set timeout until the response is received       
  ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().
          put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", "1000"); 
   String response = port.echo("testTimeout"); 
   System.out.prinltn("Received response : response");  
}
```

> This should be included in the 3.4.0 release.

Rechecked the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.ws.native/jbossws-native-core/3.4.0.GA/org/jboss/ws/core/client/transport/NettyClient.java#NettyClient.invokeInternal%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,boolean,java.util.Map,java.util.Map%29) - it's there!

Unfortunately, according to [compatibility matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-SupportedTargetContainers), jbossws-3.4.0 is supported only since JBoss AS 5.0.1.